# Do pigs have 30 minute orgasms?

Tags: zoology, ethology, sexuality

A widely circulated internet meme (see e.g. [the oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/pigs)) states that pig orgasms can last up to 30 minutes.

I've been trying to find any source or reference to back up (or refute) this claim, but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: An average boar ejaculates between 5 - 10 minutes. The total volume of semen ejaculated is typically around 4 deciliters (yes, almost a half of liter) so you can imagine it can't be completed in few seconds :) The 30 minute (various veterinary literature mentions even 40 minutes) ejaculations are edge cases, I have yet to see such an enduring boar.

Comment: To clarify, the above comment of mine was made from an answer, which was rejected because, addmitedly, I didn't read the FAQ before posting :)

Comment: Are the 30 minute orgasms supposed to be in males or females?

Comment: The fact that the boar is angry if you don't allow him to finish shows something is up. But what is this four phase ejaculation? Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

#### It seems possible but unlikely

Pig ejaculation certainly does last a long time relative to human ejaculation, and pig ejaculation is measured in minutes, not seconds.

Boar semen is collected to artificially inseminate sows. I found various guides on collecting boar semen which contain estimates for how long one should expect ejaculation to last.

Here is one estimate from the [Department of Animal Sciences Purdue University](http://www.ansc.purdue.edu/swine/porkpage/repro/pubs/basic2.htm):

> Always allow the boar to complete his ejaculation (**5-8 minutes**). If you let loose too soon, be prepared for a challenge. He will not want to leave the dummy. You will make this mistake only once or maybe twice.

[Swine Genetics International](http://www.swinegenetics.com/ai_catalog/ai_training.html):

> The boar will generally go through two to three cycles during ejaculation, taking **five to fifteen minutes** to complete the process.

[Queensland Government Primary Industries and Fisheries](http://www.dpi.qld.gov.au/27_14242.htm)

> When the penis is 'locked' in the hand and the boar relaxes, a four-phase ejaculation follows in a few seconds, taking **5 to 10 minutes** to complete.

but also:

> Large amounts of gel signal the end of ejaculation. When it is clear the boar's erection is fading, a second ejaculation can be stimulated with brief, firm, pulsating hand pressure applied to his penis.

So the largest estimate is 15 minutes, then add a possible second ejaculation of 15 minutes, that might be where the 30 minute number came from. Of course it depends on the pig! There does seem to be a large variation. More likely, the slightly more conservative estimates given here are the length of an *average* pig orgasm.

Comment: Seems to be well researched and thoroughly GROSS.

Comment: Amazing and well researched answer! I think I'll just wait a couple of days, just in case we get another answer, before accepting and awarding you the bounty.

Comment: Fantastic research, but I don't know that the length of pig ejaculations correlates to the length of pig orgasms, or if they even have them. +1 anyways :-)

Comment: @Carl, I considered that too, but there doesn't seem to be a completely clear definition of orgasm for humans. (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgasm#Definitions) "At least twenty-six definitions of orgasm were listed in the journal Clinical Psychology Review") This just seemed like the *best* way to answer the question (not the most scientific) and length of pig ejaculation *seems* to be where the meme came from anyways.